# Using scp from host to guest getting stalled

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-16.04

I try to use scp to move file from host(ubuntu 16.04 server) to guest vm (done with kvm and kimchi), but the process getting stalled after a few seconds.

Even if i try to copy the file via winscp the connection will be disconnected after a few seconds.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Below might be the reasons for getting hung, please do check once ...

1. Does your destination machine have sufficient space or inodes to reside file
2. Check your iptables or TCP wrappers for the rules to allow or deny communication
3. /etc/resolv.conf on the target system set to something resolvable
4. Are there any disks coming from NFS causing delay
5. Finally, if this could help your problem http://linuxsecure.blogspot.in/2008/05/scp-stalled-through-firewall-ssh-no.html